# Finding out paths being watched on the Firebase database with the Web SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using the Web SDK, is it possible to get a list of the database paths currently being watched and the events they're watching for?

Let's say I have the following code:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/joe/email').on('value', ...);
firebase.database().ref('/usersPosts/joe').on('child_added', ...);
```

Is there a way to ask the SDK to tell me that it's listening for *'value'* events on `/users/joe/email` and *'child_added'* events on `/usersPosts/joe`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no public API to get a list of the paths that have an active listener.

Comment: I figured, since I couldn't find anything on the docs or the object itself. Thanks, Frank!